# How do i remove index#about from the url when i come from another page to the main page section

Tags: javascript, html

So my nav looks like this: [image: navbar]

On the main page (index.html) i managed to remove the # from the url for about and services with this js code:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', e => {
  history.replaceState({}, "", location.hash.slice(1));
});
```

as when we click on them it takes us to the section on the main page but if i am on the contact.html page and i click on the about or services in the nav the url looks like this: **/index.html#about** or **/index.html#services**. I want it to show same as it does on the main page which is **/about** or **/services**.

I tried to change the href link for the links but it does not work as about and services is not a page but sections on the main page.
Here is the nav code on main page (index.html):

```
<nav>
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the nav code on contact.html page:

```
<nav>
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="/index.html#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.html#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.html#case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>
```

**When i click on about on the main page (index.html) the URL i get is something like this: https://www.example.com/about but when i click on about from contact.html page the URL is like this: https://www.example.com/index.html#about. The URL i want to get is same as on the main page without the index.html#**.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments**

1. If your server can resolve `/about` to `/about.html` then skip to the html code.
2. If your server cannot resolve `/about` to `/about.html` then you could create a folder with the name of `about` and place an `index.html` inside and it should be able to resolve.
3. Then you can link to your pages as follows:

**HTML: Multi-page**

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" class="btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**HTML: Single-page**

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#contact" class="btn">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```js
function hashHandler(){
    if ( !location.hash ) return;
    history.replaceState({}, "", location.hash.slice(1));
}

window.addEventListener( 'load', hashHandler, false );
window.addEventListener( 'hashchange', hashHandler, false );
```

Comment: I am already doing that but it does not fix it for contact.html page, look at my code

Comment: @TrueNorth please look at the anchor hrefs carefully. They are not the same as the ones in your question. What you want to use is the Multi-page example.

Comment: @TrueNorth another option would be to add a window load event to your index and check the url for a hash and run the hashchange function.

Comment: but it does not remove the # in the URL

Comment: I updated my answer to include a JS example. I think this is what you are looking for. It can be added to all your pages to handle hashes.